# Button method won't fire when using async

Tags: c#, .net, webforms

Have a simple webforms app and want to try adding chatGPT to it. Made a quick sample snippet to try it, but it won't fire?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div id="test" runat="server">
                </div>
                <asp:Button ID="btnGetData" runat="server" Text="Get Data Normally" OnClick="btnGetData_Click" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And then the code behind:

```
      protected async void btnGetData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var api = new OpenAIAPI("MY_KEY");
                var results = await api.Completions.CreateCompletionAsync(new CompletionRequest("One Two Three One Two", model: Model.CurieText, temperature: 0.1));
                test.InnerHtml = results.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                test.InnerHtml = x.ToString();
            }
        }
```

The button code won't fire? It is because I made it async? Im not getting any error messages?

Comment: I think this answer will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36710906/async-await-button-click-always-running-synchronously

Comment: Also, please review [intro to async on asp.net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net) to ensure all the requirements have been met.